# Count of values based on preceding rows

Tags: excel, counting, formulas

Some hundreds of rows of column A is filled in random order with color names (white, blue, green, yellow, red).

I need a formula in column B to show how many rows are BEFORE that row that contains the same color (standing in column A).

Example:

```
A       B
white   0
yellow  0
yellow  1
green   0
white   1
yellow  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Formula:
`=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)`

Place the formula in cell `B1` and fill down.

Answer (score 0):

you need to move your data in column **A** one row down and then put this formula in **B2**, like this:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A2)
```

[image]

And then copy and fill down the formula.